# An Apex error occurred: System.QueryException: List has more than 1 row for assignment to SObject

Tags: apex

I have 2 objects Case & Level agreement ( Don't have any relationship between both objects)
I want to compare Task Category value for both objects ...When I write below query on Apex class getting the error:

> An Apex error occurred: System.QueryException: List has more than 1
>   row for assignment to SObject

### Queries in Apex class:

```java
Case c = [select id,Task_Category__c,CaseNumber from Case where id IN:CaseId]; 
Level_Agreement__c sla = [select id,Task_Category__c,Process_Approver_email__c from Level_Agreement__c where Task_Category__c =:c.Task_Category__c];
```

---

pls, let me know is there anything missing from my side...
Thanks
Ram

Answer (score 4):

Change `Case` and `Level_Agreement__c` with `List <Case>` and `List<Level_Agreement__c>`.
You're trying to assign a List of sObjects to a single sObject

Answer (score 1):

To add to Christian's answer; if you do only expect or require one result from the query, add '[LIMIT](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_limit.htm) 1' to the end and you don't need to update the variable to a List.

Also, if your 'CaseId' is really just one Case's Id, consider amending your query to 'WHERE Id = :CaseId' rather than using '[IN](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_comparisonoperators.htm)', which is normally used when you have a list or set of values.

Comment: Thank you Dan for your help...i already identified my mistake.Your other point 'WHERE Id = :CaseId' rather than using 'IN',   i miss this small point ...Thanks Dan your help